# Python parameters and functions

Tags: python

I just started learning Python and I've just been messing around typing different codes for practice to learn, and I made this code:

```
import math
def lol():
    print (math.cos(math.pi))
    print ("I hope this works")

def print_twice(bruce):
    print bruce
    print bruce



print_twice(lol())
```

When I run it, my output is:

```
-1.0
I hope this works
None
None
```

How come it isn't printing the function lol() twice?

Answer (score 7):

Your code `print_twice(lol())` is saying to execute `lol()` and pass it's return value into `print_twice()`.  Since you didn't specify a return value for `lol()`, it returns `None`.  So, lol() is printed once when it gets executed, and both `print` statements in `print_twice()` print passed value of `None`.

This is what you want:

```
def lol():
    print (math.cos(math.pi))
    print ("I hope this works")

def print_twice(bruce):
    bruce()
    bruce()



print_twice(lol)
```

Instead of passing the *return value* of `lol()`, we are now passing the *function* `lol`, which we then execute twice in `print_twice()`.

Comment: How could I change it so it would print twice? Instead of returning None None. Is it because the function is terminate once it is called the first time in print_twice(lol())?

Answer (score 2):

You should note that printing is different from returning.

When you call `print_twice(lol())` it will first call `lol()` which will print `-1.0` and `I hope this works` and will return `None`, then it will continue calling `print_twice(None)` which will call `print None` twice.

Comment: How could I change it so it would print twice? Instead of returning None None. Is it because the function is terminate once it is called the first time in print_twice(lol())?

Comment: It will print twice, try doing `print_twice('foo')`, you only need to make sure that its argument is a string, in that case you could change `lol` so it returns something. `def lol: return 'foo'` then `print_twice(lol())` would print 'foo' twice.

Answer (score 0):

How you might run as expected:

```
def lol():
    print "lol"

def run_twice(func):
    func()
    func()

run_twice(lol)
```